# Не получается собрать cordova build ubuntu Error: missing packages click cmake

Tags: ubuntu, cordova

Пытаюсь собрать `cordova build ubuntu` в *Ubuntu 14.04*, приложение платформы ubuntu. Установлен *ubuntu SDK* и *cordova-cli*, *nodejs* разумеется тоже. 
Выполняется порядок действий:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add ubuntu
$ cordova build ubuntu
```

И вот здесь вылезает ошибка:

> Running command: /home/user/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build
>   Building...
>   Error: missing packages click cmake libicu-dev pkg-config devscripts qtbase5-dev qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev qtfeedback5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtpim5-dev libqt5sensors5-dev qtsystems5-dev
>       Install missing packages? (Yn)>

Я ввожу Y, чтобы установить недостающие пакеты, но в ответ ничего не происходит. Вернее, курсор ввода находится в крайнем левом положении, как при ожидании выполнения процесса, но вывода никакого не идет.

Как исправить ситуацию?

Пробую установить каждый пакет по отдельности и на пакете cmake вот что получается:

Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] Д
ВНИМАНИЕ: Следующие пакеты невозможно аутентифицировать!
  cmake-data

Установить эти пакеты без проверки? [y/N] y

Ош  шттп://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/ trusty/main cmake-data all 3.2.2-2ubuntu3.1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2
  404  Not Found
Получено:1 шттп://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main cmake i386 3.2.2-2ubuntu3.1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 [2.626 kB]
Получено 2.627 kБ за 3с (691 kБ/c) 
Невозможно исправить ситуацию с пропущенными пакетами.
E: Не удалось получить шттп://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake-data_3.2.2-2ubuntu3.1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Не удалось получить шттп://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake_3.2.2-2ubuntu3.1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2_i386.deb  Не совпадает размер

E: Аварийное завершение установки.

Comment: *шттп* — это, надеюсь, какая-то шутка. по поводу этого «левого» репозитория (ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/) — наверно, лучше отключить его, закомментировав строки, в которых он встречается, в файлах `/etc/apt/sources.list*`. найти имена файлов, в которых встречается эта строка: `$ grep -rl ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej /etc/apt/sources.list*`. а после этого, конечно, выполнить `$ sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь, вот решение проблемы.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

После этого все пакеты встали и cordova заработал.

Answer (score 0):

возможно, после нажатия <kbd>y</kbd> программа пытается выполнить команду `sudo apt-get install список пакетов`, но текст приглашения к вводу пароля перенаправляется куда-нибудь в лог-файл, а программа `sudo` ожидает от вас пароля.

попробуйте самостоятельно установить перечисленные недостающие пакеты прежде чем вновь выполнять `cordova build ubuntu`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install click cmake libicu-dev pkg-config devscripts qtbase5-dev qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev qtfeedback5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtpim5-dev libqt5sensors5-dev qtsystems5-dev
```

---

а чтобы прервать ожидание ввода, можно нажать <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Я немного пропустил, там после ввода Y действительно просило пароль а потом тишина. Попробовал как вы написали но в ответ увидел вот это: Установить эти пакеты без проверки? [y/N] y
E: Некоторые пакеты невозможно аутентифицировать

Comment: @edarium, «Некоторые пакеты невозможно аутентифицировать» — ну, вы уже подключили по крайней мере один «левый» репозиторий. «снявши голову по волосам не плачут». соглашайтесь установить без проверки (нажимайте `y`).

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.